# How to zoom in on center of svg zoom box that is in view

Tags: javascript, math, svg, zooming

Hello i am trying to add zooming in my svg what i am trying to do is to zoom on center of the box that is currently visible on screen. i need that because their is panning so if someone drag. the box and it is only half in view so then i had to zoom on the center part of the box that is in view. i have provided the codePen please check it out

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/Owais-Ahmad/pen/poQyVoe)

```
const panBox = document.querySelector(".pan-box");
const zoomBox = document.querySelector(".zoom-box");

const dot = document.querySelector("#dot");
const table = document.querySelector("#table");
const tableGroup = document.querySelectorAll(".round-table");

const addDragAndPanning = Draggable.create(".round-table, .pan-box", {
  onPress: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});

let radius = gsap.getProperty(table, "r");
const changeCircleSize = Draggable.create(dot, {
  type: "y",
  onDragStart: function () {
    dragCircle[0].disable();
  },
  onDrag: function () {
    table.setAttribute(
      "r",
      gsap.utils.clamp(20, Infinity, Math.abs(radius - this.y))
    );
  },
  onDragEnd: function () {
    dragCircle[0].enable();
  }
});

/* ------------------ ZOOM ----------------- */

window.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
let zoom = 1;
function onWheel(event) {

  /* --------------------- Responsible for Zoom in and out -------------------- */
  let delta = event.wheelDelta;
  if (delta > 0) {
    svgBox.style.transform =
      zoom >= 0.08 ? `scale(${(zoom -= 0.02)})` : `scale(${zoom})`;
  } else {
    svgBox.style.transform =
      zoom < 1.3 ? `scale(${(zoom += 0.02)})` : `scale(${zoom})`;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Here are the Explaining images

[image: Image: 1]

[image: Image: 2]

[image: Image 3]

I tried different ways searched on stackoverflow but can't make it. Most of the answers were on image but i am trying this in svg. Please help me solve this.

Comment: I could not understand what is the desired behaviour, i copied the code and runned in here and got this: https://prnt.sc/FD97TMgTWFHX

Comment: it should start zoomed? the zoom control you talk about is to drag the red ball or to actualy zoom like scrolling in the mouse/pressing ctrl + -

Comment: @PauloFernando No no, the red dot has nothing to do here, and you don't need to copy the code it's already in codepen Please check it out it's in the top section under the paragraph you can check its current behavior in codepen. And it should zoom in and out using the mouse wheel event however the zoom is implemented already but its the location on which the zoom focuses on which in my case i want it to be the center point of the svg and not the zoom box(g element) please check out the images and codepen you'll understand what i am saying.

Comment: @PauloFernando in simple words:- i want to scale an svg children g element using its parent svg element transform origin center point which is 50% 50% for svg but the challange is how to use this origin of svg for its g children

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about what you need to do is to follow these three steps when you zoom.

1. Translate the SVG so that the SVG coordinates, that are where your pointer is, are now at the origin (0,0)
2. Scale the SVG by your zoom ratio
3. Translate the SVG back in the opposite direction to the pointer position.
   But remember that the translate distance will now be different because the SVG has been scaled.  So you'll need to divide the translate coords by the amount you just zoomed.

You may have a few problems because you are using a third-party library for your panning, and your own code for the zoom.

But I hope this helps you get there.

Comment: I've tried scaling svg itself but that doesn't work (because it scales the svg which disrupts the whole svg and thats not a good experience todo) I have to scale the g element. can you please check out the code pen and see it there I've seen this type of zoom in many places. 

[Zoom reference webiste](https://planning.wedding). Here if you sign in and move to reception layout their they have this type of zoom and they are using transltae x, y with scale on g element

Comment: I know their is some heavy math here and i am getting the values of g element using the getboudclientrect() and also the svg values using getboudclientrect(). i tried different type calculations to find x , y for the scale but haven't been successfull.

Following calculations i have done:

1: ( gBottom - bTop ) / 2 -> for translate y
    (gRight - gLeft) / 2 -> for translate x

2: (gWidth - svgWidth) + gLeft -> for translate x
    (gHeight - svgHeight) + gTop -> for translate y

Comment: I have updated the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Owais-Ahmad/pen/poQyVoe) if you check it out now you'll understand.